# Watir - using proxy in Firefox with authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I want to set up a proxy in Firefox with Watir.
The proxy requires authentication - username and password.

I get error when I want to do the following thing:

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile.proxy = Selenium::WebDriver::Proxy.new :http => "user:pass@133.212.109.502:8080"
```

The error is:

```
ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "pass@133.212.109.502:8080"
```

What am I doing wrong?
How to use proxy with authentication in Firefox properly?

Thanks for help

Comment: Were you able to figure this out ?

Comment: did you solve it @Aljaz ? cause i have similar problem

Comment: I think the solution is to use http:// as a prefix in the string